# Can AspectJ find all variable declarations and log them in a method?

Tags: aop, aspectj

For example, I have a java method like this:

```
public void hello() {
   String name = "Freewind";
   String message = "Welcome";
   System.out.println(message + name);
}
```

Then I want to use AspectJ to log the variables:

```
public void hello() {
   String name = "Freewind";
   log("New variable: name");           // by aspectj
   String message = "Welcome";
   log("New variable: message");           // by aspectj
   System.out.println(message + name);
}
```

Is it possible with AspectJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Sorry for the brief answer, but there is not much more to say about it.